# Get first and last line item for each day in given range

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I have a db table that has multiple line items for each day (one per hour). When querying the db, I can get items for each day and can filter by date range and time like this:

```
SELECT * FROM readings 
WHERE date_recorded > '2022-01-01' 
AND date_recorded < '2022-01-15' 
AND time_recorded > '08:00:00' 
AND time_recorded < '17:00:00';
```

(Yes, I realize that I can do a `BETWEEN`, but that's not how this query is currently built out, so this is what I have to work with).

This will give me all readings between 8 and 5 for the given date range. But I would like to get just the first and last reading for every day. I can do a `SELECT MIN()` operation and union it with a `SELECT MAX()` operation, but within the current query, that will only give me the first and last reading of the entire date range (i.e. 2022-01-01 08:00:00 and 2022-01-15 17:00:00), and I need the first and last for every day.

I know that I can do some cleanup of the date through looping the results AFTER they have been pulled, but I was wondering if there was a clean way to do this all in one command within MariaDB (MySQL)?

I don't know if this makes a difference, but I will be doing this within a PHP framework using PDO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On MySQL 8+, we can use `ROW_NUMBER()` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY date_recorded ORDER BY time_recorded) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY date_recorded ORDER BY time_recorded DESC) rn2
    FROM readings
    WHERE date_recorded BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-01-15' AND
          time_recorded BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '17:00:00'
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn1 = 1 OR rn2 = 1
ORDER BY date_recorded, time_recorded;
```

Comment: I've been trying this, but I think I have an outdated version. I feel like this will work perfectly, but I need to get some updates.

Comment: After getting all the updates, this worked. Thank you.

Comment: MySQL 5.7 will be reaching end of life soon (I think).  Upgrading to 8+ is the best decision.